# Are Jinns real and can they harm you?

Tags: jinn

In many Islamic countries they believe that one can get possesed by jins. However non muslims do not believe this and they say it is just a health (mental) problem when someone behave in a not so normal manner.

If jinns are real how can we avoid them?

Comment: [Step by step guide followed by Jinn to harm you](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0usGDDlyK7A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinns are real and in English terms they're called "shadow people" or plasma beings.

Iblis is a jinn, and the bad jinns are shaytans.

There's a Surah al-Jinn in the Quran, Surah #72, and many ayahs speaking of jinns, like from Surah al-Hijr 15:27=

**"And the jinn We created before from scorching fire."**

The idea of jinns possessing our bodies is problematic.  There's no ayah or sahih hadith that tells us jinns can do it.

Most, incidences of possession were cases of mentally unstable person.  People confused it with jinn possession.

However, jinns can harm us without possessing a human.  They can throw things, strike fear and even make us see things that aren't there.  But can they take over our body?  No ayah or hadith says they can.  But no ayah or hadith says they can't either.

Scholars debated the actuality of possession for over a thousand years.

Comment: I suggest that you read this answer [here](https://islamqa.info/en/1819)

Comment: Also, please try your best to add references to your answer when you deny a fact that the majority of Muslims, if not all of them, believe in it. I myself had an experience with a friend of mine who was possessed by 10 Jinns. I spoke to them and they spoke to me, and I learned so much about Jinns from that experience.

Answer (score 0):

When Allah (SWT) has said that they are real, then no doubt is left that if they do not exist. They do exist, and they can harm us. And to protect yourself from Bad jinns, you have to recite last 2 Chapters of Quran and Ayat ul kursi.

Answer (score -3):

No there are nothing but something called [ghost] [spirit] etc at that time
In bible they are mentioned as demon
In quran as jinn

Comment: Do you mind adding a reference from either Qur'an or hadith?