# Can Satan or jinn do physical harm to a person?

Tags: shaitan, jinn, sihr

Can Satan or jinn do physical harm to a person? If so, does isolation of a person help them to do that more in any way? Or is whispering to us to do bad  his only act?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean in the final sentence, "Does isolation of us help them to do that more in anyway?"

Comment: Salam, Isolation means tends to live alone..I saw in a discussion that isolation of a person may give the jinn more chances to attack.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are Jinns real and can they harm you?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12324/are-jinns-real-and-can-they-harm-you)

Comment: uh-huh, yeah, @servant-of-Wiser is right, the second part of the mentioned link could be related to what you are looking for. http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12324/are-jinns-real-and-can-they-harm-you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ask will they come and slap us while we're alone, then I would say I'm not sure about it, if such incidents have ever occured.

But if you ask will they cause us to slap ourselves then the answer is **YES**.

This second one they accomplish only by whispering in our hearts and commanding us to slap ourselves (how? that depends on Satan's trick).

Also, as Hamza Islam said, isolation couldn't be considered as a factor, it is the measure of remembrance of Allah which could be considered a factor, since

> And whosoever turns away (blinds himself) from the remembrance of the Most Beneficent (Allah) (i.e. this Quran and worship of Allah), We appoint for him Shaitan (Satan - devil) to be a Qarin (an intimate companion) to him. (Qur'an 43:36)

I suggest, you to watch this, a bit long though, but a good one - [Getting started with Jinns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0usGDDlyK7A)

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: Well explained.. this answers my question. Btw, then they just make us to do whatever they want, but don't become visible to us and come to hit us. And they don't do anything magical, because i got to know from someone that something weird happened to her house. So, these things are just a misconceptions? If so, then we just have to understand which is the whispering of satan and which one is right to do?

Comment: [Which sins are related to Satan? which sins are related to carnal soul (Nafs-al-Ammarah)?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17560/which-sins-are-related-to-satan-which-sins-are-related-to-carnal-soul-nafs-al) and also plz feel free to watch that video completely, u'll understand better... @NadiaAli

Comment: Good one. And yes I watched the video 25% yesterday, its ineteresting, will watch it completely. Jazakallah Khair.

Answer (score 2):

Walecum salam,

Yes, the jinn can physically harm us. The jinn can possess us as well (stay inside human beings and control the body to certain level, sometimes fully).

Yes, they can whisper to us as well, as it is made clear in Surah Al-Nas of Quran.

Isolation doesn't matter much if someone is possessed by the jinn. If they wish to harm us, they can harm us even if we are not in isolation.

Comment: Reference for possession?

Comment: @Zohal: www.islamicboard.com/aqeedah/134283614-reality-jinn-possession.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can physically harm us. They can also whisper in your ears as you said, but keep in mind that just like there are good and bad humans, there are also good and bad jinns, and there are even Muslim jinns (although you would never come across one, because it is forbidden for jinns to interact with us in any way just like we can't interact with them). Regarding the isolation of a person, yes that may have an effect, as jinn generally like to stay where people aren't. May Allah protect us from the shaytaan alrajeem, and from all evil, amen.

Comment: Sister, i know people who directly interact with jinns, even i have seen a woman possessed with jin, the jinn inside her interacted openly with the scholar,who was doing ruqya on her. the jinn accepted islam and left the body of that woman, and it happened after convesation with him

Comment: @HamzaIslam yes, i  have seen it too. the jinninside of her would have obviously been a bad jinn, until the scholar's conversation (by the will of Allah of course). the interaction of jinn that i am talking about is those who use the jinn for their aid. for example, psychics, magicians musicians, etc. to be honest, i dont understand the concept of interacting with a jinn when it has possessed someone, but i guess it would be acceptable if they are saving the person, otherwise the scholars wouldnt do it

Comment: The scholar did not do ruqya to interact with him,but with the intention of curing him. so you are right, interaction is possible, but just forbidden

Comment: How'd someone will understand if he.she is possessed by a jinn?

Comment: @NadiaAli: there are multiple symptoms, most common are bad dreams, like animals trying to attack you, specially dog, lizard, looking filth like urine and feces, looking too much dirt, some one attacking you, seeing too much water, physical symptoms include that the person gets angry without any reason to extremes, having straneg peranality, being quite suddenly, sudden change in personality, not micing up with people, and some more like these

Comment: @HamzaIslam Chances are that your friend is probably suffering from a mental disability. To directly associate that with a jinn possession is non-sense. Maybe some medical attention is in order. If she is actually "possessed by a jinn", scientists would have a field day.

Comment: @masfenix: thanks for your opinion,but she came to that scholar after suffering fro 16 years, she went to UK specialists as well. neuro surgeons, experts of many fields, but ALL Failed, and only This solution worked..

Comment: @HamzaIslam what scholar? You believe  an Islamic scholar is capable of curing (most likely a mental disability) that medical specialists ALL FAILED to do so? I highly highly doubt that. In fact you never even mentioned what was wrong with her, you said `I have seen a woman possessed with jin`. Tell me, sir, what does a person possessed with jin look like?

Comment: @masfenix:yes, i believe so, because ALL of the major most senior experts of medical science and experts of other fields completely failed to diagnose this problem, and gave up. 
What other choice do i have to Not believe? that where all the major experts failed, at that place, Islamic scholar took few days to cut root of this problem? is there any logical explanation left ?

Answer (score 1):

Assalam ol Alaikum wa rahmatollah. In order to reply to your attractive question that is "Can Jinns and Satan harm people physically?", I am telling you that Yes, it is possible that jinn harm people. But there is an important matter that you should be aware of, and that is about the limitation of their abilities and power to do that. In fact they cannot harm wherever and whoever. Then you should not worry much about it.

So to be confident, you may recite Quran or other duas like :
Besmellahe rahmane rahim, La hawla wa la kovata ela bellah al aliel azim. (According to my medium knowledge)

Answer (score 0):

They can't physically attack us viz can't slap. they even not communicate with us without medium. But they able to attack our thought. descend on us or may influence others, Human or other creature to attack us.

And remember Our servant Job, when he called to his Lord, "Indeed, Satan has touched me with hardship and torment." - 38:41

Answer (score 0):

Jinn cannot communicate nor harm us unknowingly or knowingly. The jinns live in other world whereas humans live in other world.  Jinn can only cause harm if we call them for e.g.: witchcraft, black magic, fortune telling, etc. These are the things that can make a jinn cause harm to you and also kill you . If you did any of these the jinn will not leave us they can scare us, unless it can be cured by Quran. May Allah protect us from these.

You can do the following things to prevent being possessed by jinn:

1. remember allah and prophet muhammed(SAW) every time
2. recite ayat-ul-kursi and do read Quran on daily basis
3. do thikr

Comment: Try adding references in support for you answer.